julia_eval reordering parameter labels when converting object to RDS
When returning a GeneralizedLinearMixedModel result using julia_eval I get estimates in the subsequently saved .rds that are out of order with the labels in julia.
The code below will develop a dataset using the same values present in my 'real' data:
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)
library(tidyr)
library(bbmle)
library(JuliaCall)

julia<- julia_setup()
julia_library("MixedModels")
julia_library("RCall")
julia_library("JellyMe4")

Analysisclass_set1<- c("Wetland_Wet_night", "Wetland_Wet_day","Wetland_Dry_day",
                      "Wetland_Dry_night","aRice_Wet_night")
Analysisclass_set2<- c("aRice_Wet_day","Fallow grains and grasslands_Wet_night",
                      "Fallow grains and grasslands_Wet_day", "Fallow grains and grasslands_Dry_day",
                      "Fallow grains and grasslands_Dry_night", "aRice_Dry_night",
                      "Nonhabitat_Dry_day","Nonhabitat_Dry_night",
                      "Nonhabitat_Wet_night","Nonhabitat_Wet_day")
cropyear<- c("10_2023", "11_2023", "12_2023", "1_2024", "2_2024", "3_2024")
individual_local_identifier = c("236003.1", "236000.1", "235970.1", "235981.1", "235984.1", "236006.1", "236005.1", "235985.1", "232852.1", "236001.1", "232867.1", "236009.1", "235983.2")

xdata2<- data.frame(
  case = rep(0:1,c(22500,2250)),
  Analysisclass =  c(sample(Analysisclass_set1,12375,replace = TRUE),sample(Analysisclass_set2,12375,replace = TRUE)),
  cropyear = sample(cropyear, 24750, replace = T),
  individual_local_identifier = sample(individual_local_identifier, 24750, replace = T)
)

xdata2$weights<- 1000^(1-xdata2$case)
  
julia_assign("m0form", formula(case ~ 0 + Analysisclass + (1|cropyear/individual_local_identifier)))
julia_assign("data", xdata2)

julia_command(sprintf('Jmodel = fit(GeneralizedLinearMixedModel, m0form, data, Bernoulli(), wts=float.(data.weights), contrasts= Dict(:Analysisclass => DummyCoding(base="aRice_Wet_day")))'))
juliamodel<- julia_eval("robject(:glmerMod, Tuple([Jmodel, data]));",need_return ="R")                                   
summary(juliamodel)

The Julia output looks like this:
> julia_command(sprintf('Jmodel = fit(GeneralizedLinearMixedModel, m0form, data, Bernoulli(), wts=float.(data.weights), contrasts= Dict(:Analysisclass => DummyCoding(base="aRice_Wet_day")))'))
Generalized Linear Mixed Model fit by maximum likelihood (nAGQ = 1)
  case ~ 0 + Analysisclass + (1 | cropyear) + (1 | cropyear & individual_local_identifier)
  Distribution: Bernoulli{Float64}
  Link: LogitLink()

   logLik     deviance      AIC         AICc        BIC     
 -21168.8674  42337.7348  42371.7348  42371.7596  42509.7167

Variance components:
                                          Column    Variance  Std.Dev. 
cropyear & individual_local_identifier (Intercept)  0.0053981 0.0734720
cropyear                               (Intercept)  0.0035934 0.0599448

 Number of obs: 24750; levels of grouping factors: 78, 6

Fixed-effects parameters:
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                           Coef.    Std. Error        z  Pr(>|z|)
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Analysisclass: Fallow grains and grasslands_Dry_day     -8.32832     0.0701135  -118.78    <1e-99
Analysisclass: Fallow grains and grasslands_Dry_night   -8.37067     0.071448   -117.16    <1e-99
Analysisclass: Fallow grains and grasslands_Wet_day     -8.43396     0.0730159  -115.51    <1e-99
Analysisclass: Fallow grains and grasslands_Wet_night   -8.39096     0.0696173  -120.53    <1e-99
Analysisclass: Nonhabitat_Dry_day                       -8.2924      0.0675942  -122.68    <1e-99
Analysisclass: Nonhabitat_Dry_night                     -8.39535     0.0717284  -117.04    <1e-99
Analysisclass: Nonhabitat_Wet_day                       -8.51558     0.0748724  -113.73    <1e-99
Analysisclass: Nonhabitat_Wet_night                     -8.43524     0.0707701  -119.19    <1e-99
Analysisclass: Wetland_Dry_day                         -21.8676     35.1906       -0.62    0.5343
Analysisclass: Wetland_Dry_night                       -33.0785   9748.6          -0.00    0.9973
Analysisclass: Wetland_Wet_day                         -22.241      42.9997       -0.52    0.6050
Analysisclass: Wetland_Wet_night                       -23.1143     65.814        -0.35    0.7254
Analysisclass: aRice_Dry_night                          -8.48436     0.0734606  -115.50    <1e-99
Analysisclass: aRice_Wet_day                            -8.51622     0.0744023  -114.46    <1e-99
Analysisclass: aRice_Wet_night                         -24.787     154.132        -0.16    0.8722
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

The summary output of the glmerMod converted back to R is:
> summary(juliamodel)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: case ~ 0 + Analysisclass + (1 | cropyear) + (1 | cropyear:individual_local_identifier)
   Data: jellyme4_data
Weights: jellyme4_weights
Control: lme4::glmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxeval = 1), optimizer = "nloptwrap",  
    calc.derivs = FALSE, check.nobs.vs.rankZ = "warning", check.nobs.vs.nlev = "warning",  
    check.nlev.gtreq.5 = "ignore", check.nlev.gtr.1 = "warning",      check.nobs.vs.nRE = "warning", check.rankX = "message+drop.cols",  
    check.scaleX = "warning", check.formula.LHS = "stop")

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 66346.9  66484.9 -33156.5  66312.9    24733 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
       0        0        0        0 17689096 

Random effects:
 Groups                               Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 cropyear:individual_local_identifier (Intercept) 0.005398 0.07347 
 cropyear                             (Intercept) 0.003593 0.05994 
Number of obs: 24750, groups:  cropyear:individual_local_identifier, 78; cropyear, 6

Fixed effects:
                                                      Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
AnalysisclassaRice_Dry_night                        -8.328e+00  7.509e-02 -110.918   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassaRice_Wet_day                          -8.371e+00  7.637e-02 -109.610   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassaRice_Wet_night                        -8.434e+00  5.460e-02 -154.455   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassFallow grains and grasslands_Dry_day   -8.391e+00  7.887e-02 -106.389   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassFallow grains and grasslands_Dry_night -8.292e+00  7.553e-02 -109.793   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassFallow grains and grasslands_Wet_day   -8.395e+00  7.858e-02 -106.835   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassFallow grains and grasslands_Wet_night -8.516e+00  8.047e-02 -105.817   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassNonhabitat_Dry_day                     -8.435e+00  7.868e-02 -107.207   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassNonhabitat_Dry_night                   -2.187e+01  6.240e+01   -0.350    0.726    
AnalysisclassNonhabitat_Wet_day                     -3.308e+01  1.677e+04   -0.002    0.998    
AnalysisclassNonhabitat_Wet_night                   -2.224e+01  7.255e+01   -0.307    0.759    
AnalysisclassWetland_Dry_day                        -2.311e+01  7.276e+01   -0.318    0.751    
AnalysisclassWetland_Dry_night                      -8.484e+00  5.574e-02 -152.216   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassWetland_Wet_day                        -8.516e+00  5.622e-02 -151.488   <2e-16 ***
AnalysisclassWetland_Wet_night                      -2.479e+01  1.683e+02   -0.147    0.883    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 15 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it

optimizer (LN_BOBYQA) convergence code: 5 (fit with MixedModels.jl)

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/Los_Angeles
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] JuliaCall_0.17.5 bbmle_1.0.25.1   tidyr_1.3.1      lme4_1.1-35.3    Matrix_1.7-0     vroom_1.6.5      lubridate_1.9.3  sf_1.0-16       
[9] dplyr_1.1.4     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.4          generics_0.1.3      class_7.3-22        KernSmooth_2.23-22  lattice_0.22-6      magrittr_2.0.3      grid_4.4.0         
 [8] timechange_0.3.0    mvtnorm_1.2-5       e1071_1.7-14        DBI_1.2.2           purrr_1.0.2         fansi_1.0.6         codetools_0.2-20   
[15] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 cli_3.6.2           rlang_1.1.3         crayon_1.5.2        units_0.8-5         bit64_4.0.5         splines_4.4.0      
[22] withr_3.0.0         parallel_4.4.0      tools_4.4.0         tzdb_0.4.0          nloptr_2.0.3        bdsmatrix_1.3-7     minqa_1.2.7        
[29] boot_1.3-30         vctrs_0.6.5         R6_2.5.1            proxy_0.4-27        lifecycle_1.0.4     classInt_0.4-10     bit_4.0.5          
[36] MASS_7.3-60.2       pkgconfig_2.0.3     terra_1.7-78        pillar_1.9.0        glue_1.7.0          Rcpp_1.0.12         xfun_0.44          
[43] tibble_3.2.1        tidyselect_1.2.1    rstudioapi_0.16.0   knitr_1.46          nlme_3.1-164        compiler_4.4.0


Is this a problem? Isn't it just printing the coefficients in a different order? Remember that jellyme4 is alpha software..

It appears that MixedModels is printing parameters in ASCIIbetical order while R is printing them in alphabetical order. What problem is this causing in your code?
